# Why are my comments moving the page down?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on page that displays user posts.  I would like to keep all of the content from this page contained within the window so the viewer doesn't have to scroll down.

Right now the page contains posts, comments, and the replies to the comments.  The posts will stay on the left side of the page while comments and replies stay on the right side of the page.

So far everything is on the correct side of the page, and my content fits within the window until the post gets comments and replies.  When a post has comments an extra bit of space is placed underneath the post on the left side even though my comments are stored on the right side of the page.

I was wondering if someone could look at my code and explain why the extra space is added below the post when there are comments on the right side.

If you have any other questions I will be more than happy to answer.

My code

```
<div class="homeBody">
        <?php
            getPost($conn);
        ?>
</div> ...
function getPost($conn) { ...

                        if (mysqli_num_rows($commentresult)==0) {
                            echo '';
                        }
                        else {
                            $commenterid = $commentrow['userid'];
                            $commentersql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '$commenterid'";
                            $commenterresult = mysqli_query($conn, $commentersql);
                            while ($commenterrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commenterresult)) {

                                echo    '<div class="PostCommentSet"> <div class="PostComments">';

                                    if ($commenterrow['profileimg'] == 1) {
                                        $filename = "profilepics/profile".$commenterid."*";
                                        $fileinfo = glob($filename);
                                        $fileext = explode(".", $fileinfo[0]);
                                        $fileactualext = $fileext[1];
                                        echo "<div class='CommentProfilePicture'><img src='profilepics/profile".$commenterid.".".$fileactualext."?".mt_rand()."'></div>";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo "<div class='CommentProfilePicture'><img src='profilepics/noUser.png'></div>";
                                    }

                                echo    "<div class='CommentUserName'>".$commenterrow['userName']."</div>";
                                echo    "<div class='CommenterComment'>".$commentrow['comment']."</div> </div>";
                            }

                            $currentcommentid = $commentrow['commentid'];
                            $replysql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE hostid = '$hostid' AND postid = '$postid' AND commentid = '$currentcommentid' AND replyid > 0";
                            $replyresult = mysqli_query($conn, $replysql);
                            while ($replyrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($replyresult)) {
                                if (mysqli_num_rows($replyresult)==0) {
                                    echo '';
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo '
                                            <div class="PostReplies">
                                                <div class="ReplierReply">'.$replyrow['reply'].'</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    ';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

My Css

```
.homeBody {
        margin: 60px 0px 37px 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100vh - 97px);
        background-color: #777;

    }
.PostBox {
        width: 65%;
        height: calc(100vh - 97px);
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
        position: relative;
    }
    .PostImg {
        width: 60%;
        height: 70vh;
        object-fit: contain;
    }
    .PostCommentSet {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 60px;
        width: 30%;
    }
    .PostComments {
        background-color: #555;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: white;
    }
    .PostReplies {
        background-color: #555;
        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
        right: 0px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    /* Comments */

        .CommentUserName {
            position: relative;
            left: 40px;
            top: -25px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 550;
        }
        .CommentProfilePicture {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .CommentProfilePicture img {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            object-fit: cover;
            top: 1px;
            left: 1px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .CommenterComment {
            position: relative;
            left: 40px;
            top: -8px;
        }
        .ReplierReply {

        }
```

Comment: You need to show us only the relevant bits of the code (this is too much for anyone who decides not to spend more than a few minutes on it), or recreate the problem (either here as a code snippet or jsfiddle or... etc.) I know it's not easy, but you'll get quicker/better answers like that.

Comment: I will try to edit it down, I thought maybe there might have been a mistake earlier on but you are right give me a few minutes to correct this.

Comment: Yeah, maybe try extracting the rendered HTML in both versions (with comments and without). Also, offtopic, but that code is vulnerable to MySQL injection (http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php).

Comment: It is indeed.  Thank you for letting me know.  This is somewhat of test code and I plan on finalizing it very soon.

Comment: I am looking at two different posts, that both hold the same content.  One has a comment and a reply while the second one does not.  The second one fits the page perfectly so I'm thinking it has to be the comment or the reply messing things up.

Comment: No problem. I think the layout bug comes from `<div class="PostCommentSet">` never being closed. Looks like you have one less closed div tag than you have open ones. EDIT: Seems like you're closing that tag in your "replies" part, which means if you have a comment, but no replies, the whole HTML structure would break (browsers usually try to patch it up for you, but that never ends up well)

Comment: Ah yea that was a problem but the space is still there, I added another closing div tag to the reply section if there werent a reply so it should be closing properly all the time now.

Comment: I opened the inspection menu in chrome and I think I figured out that the div class .homeBody is what is getting extra space when there are comments or replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have any width or height set for the actual comment and reply div tags